# IIS websites for static and dynamic contents

Tags: performance, web, iis, dynamic, static

Can we divide a web application into two websites on IIS - one for hosting only static files ( js, css, images, fonts) with port 80 and other for dynamic contents generating programs ( web services, c# programs ) , with port 81 ? Request will come to static website, if it is for static files, it will be served from port 80 website, if not request will be redirected to port 81 website ( where dynamic contents generating programs reside ) ? Will it improve the performance as port 81 website will be free from serving the static files and more focused on the program execution?

Comment: Once you really understand the modular design of IIS, you can see your idea is not worth the while, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture Static/dynamic contents are handled by different handlers, so there is no extra overhead (which can be very much in your proposed approach).

Comment: Thanks Lex for your response. Question : Does all the modules run in the same process of IIS ? or separate process is spawn for the same ?

Comment: I cannot answer this question you raised in comment, as it still shows misunderstanding. Alternatively, I can say that whenever an IIS worker process is created, it loads all the modules it should (based on the relevant settings of that application pool, and of the sites/applications it runs). IIS only manages its own worker processes, and usually don't spawn other processes (except FastCGI/.NET Core, but they don't load IIS modules).

Comment: I assumed that any misunderstanding or doubts or questions are cleared in this forum :) Anyway thanks for your response.